# Yii2 kartik-datecontrol extension

Tags: yii2

I installed the above extension via composer and follow the documentation for every step; in my :

```
view : use kartik\datecontrol\DateControl;// <?=$form->field($model, 'dated')->widget(DateControl::classname(), [
                        'type'=>DateControl::FORMAT_DATE,
                        'ajaxConversion'=>false,
                        'options' => ['pluginOptions' => ['autoclose' => true ],'class'=>'col-xs-12 form-control input-sm']])?>

Web.php - Module configuration :
use \kartik\datecontrol\Module;

 'datecontrol' =>  [
        'class' => 'kartik\datecontrol\Module',

        // format settings for displaying each date attribute (ICU format example)
        'displaySettings' => [
            Module::FORMAT_DATE => 'php:dd-m-Y',
            Module::FORMAT_TIME => 'php:H:i:s',
            Module::FORMAT_DATETIME => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s', 
        ],

        // format settings for saving each date attribute (PHP format example)
        'saveSettings' => [
            Module::FORMAT_DATE => 'php:Y-m-d', 
            Module::FORMAT_TIME => 'php:H:i:s',
            Module::FORMAT_DATETIME => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s',
        ],

        // set your display timezone
//        'displayTimezone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',

        // set your timezone for date saved to db
//        'saveTimezone' => 'UTC',

        // automatically use kartik\widgets for each of the above formats
        'autoWidget' => true,

        // default settings for each widget from kartik\widgets used when autoWidget is true
        'autoWidgetSettings' => [
            Module::FORMAT_DATE => ['type'=>2, 'pluginOptions'=>['autoclose'=>true]], // example
            Module::FORMAT_DATETIME => [], // setup if needed
            Module::FORMAT_TIME => [], // setup if needed
        ],

        // custom widget settings that will be used to render the date input instead of kartik\widgets,
        // this will be used when autoWidget is set to false at module or widget level.
        'widgetSettings' => [
            Module::FORMAT_DATE => [
                'class' => 'yii\jui\DatePicker', // example
                'options' => [
                    'dateFormat' => 'php:d-M-Y',
                    'options' => ['class'=>'form-control'],
                ]
            ]
        ]
        // other settings
    ]
```

When I run the view I got the following error message :

> {"name":"Invalid Configuration","message":"The class
>   '\kartik\date\DatePicker' was not found and is required for
>   DateControl 'date' format.\n\nPlease ensure you have installed one of
>   'yii2-widgets' OR 'yii2-widget-datepicker' extensions. To install, you
>   can run this console command from your application root:\n\nphp
>   composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-widgets: \"@dev\"\n\n--- OR
>   ---\n\nphp composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker: \"@dev\"","code":0,"type":"yii\base\InvalidConfigException","file":"C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\kartik-v\yii2-krajee-base\Config.php","line":118,"stack-trace":["#0
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\kartik-v\yii2-krajee-base\Config.php(195):
>   kartik\base\Config::checkDependency('\\kartik\\date\\Da...',
>   Array, 'for DateControl...')","#1
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\kartik-v\yii2-datecontrol\DateControl.php(215):
>   kartik\base\Config::validateInputWidget('\\kartik\\date\\Da...',
>   'for DateControl...')","#2
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\kartik-v\yii2-datecontrol\DateControl.php(154):
>   kartik\datecontrol\DateControl->initConfig()","#3
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php(107):
>   kartik\datecontrol\DateControl->init()","#4 [internal function]:
>   yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)","#5
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(372):
>   ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)","#6
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(151):
>   yii\di\Container->build('kartik\\datecont...', Array, Array)","#7
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(344):
>   yii\di\Container->get('kartik\\datecont...', Array, Array)","#8
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Widget.php(97):
>   yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)","#9
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\ActiveField.php(665):
>   yii\base\Widget::widget(Array)","#10
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\views\activite\schedules.php(49):
>   yii\widgets\ActiveField->widget('kartik\\datecont...',
>   Array)","#11
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(325):
>   require('C:\\wamp\\www\\pub...')","#12
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(247):
>   yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('C:\\wamp\\www\\pub...',
>   Array)","#13
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(149):
>   yii\base\View->renderFile('C:\\wamp\\www\\pub...', Array,
>   Object(app\controllers\ActiviteController))","#14
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(371):
>   yii\base\View->render('schedules', Array,
>   Object(app\controllers\ActiviteController))","#15
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\controllers\ActiviteController.php(407):
>   yii\base\Controller->render('schedules', Array)","#16 [internal
>   function]:
>   app\controllers\ActiviteController->actionAddsch('4')","#17
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(55):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)","#18
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(151):
>   yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)","#19
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(455):
>   yii\base\Controller->runAction('addsch', Array)","#20
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(84):
>   yii\base\Module->runAction('activite/addsch', Array)","#21
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375):
>   yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))","#22
>   C:\wamp\www\pub\web\index.php(12):
>   yii\base\Application->run()","#23 {main}"]}

Comment: first you must have `kartik\date\DatePicker` extension to use date control.

Comment: so you mean I have also to install kartik\date\DatePicker,kartik\date\TimePicker and kartik\date\DatetimePicker?

Comment: Error says that you need to install `kartik-v/yii2-widgets` **OR** `kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker`

Comment: kartik-v/yii2-widgets OR kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker was not installed that's why, After it installation it is working now!!!

Answer (score 4):

Try installing the following widgets:

yii2-widget-datepicker
yii2-widget-datetimepicker

or better, install the kartik widgets using composer:

```
php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-widgets "*"
```

that will install the following widgets:

- yii2-krajee-base
- yii2-widget-activeform
- yii2-widget-affix
- yii2-widget-alert
- yii2-widget-colorinput
- yii2-widget-datepicker
- yii2-widget-datetimepicker
- yii2-widget-depdrop
- yii2-widget-fileinput
- yii2-widget-growl
- yii2-widget-rangeinput
- yii2-widget-rating
- yii2-widget-select2
- yii2-widget-sidenav
- yii2-widget-spinner
- yii2-widget-switchinput
- yii2-widget-timepicker
- yii2-widget-touchspin
- yii2-widget-typeahead

Comment: thats a little overkill, if he only wants datepicker/datetimepicker